# Как сделать всё и сразу в mod_rewrite?

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite, faq

Я пишу сайт на PHP, использую сервер Apache. Мне надо сделать редирект с адреса www, человекочитаемые URL, редирект на канонический URL, мультиязычность, запретить некоторые юзер-агенты, забанить пользователей по IP и ещё много чего с помощью mod_rewrite, причём чтобы всё это настраивалось через админку.

Как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Вы идёте неправильным путём. Если делать всё через mod_rewrite, то вы столкнётесь с кучей проблем:

- Вы погрязнете в тоннах нечитаемого и неподдерживаемого кода. Этот язык не предназначен для сложной логики, хоть он и условно полон по Тьюрингу.
- Вы намертво прибьёте свой сайт гвоздями к серверу Apache. Если вы захотите воспользоваться nginx, то у вас возникнут серьёзные проблемы.
- Отлаживать правила практически невозможно. Если вы столкнётесь с багом, который не исправляется пристальным взглядом на код, то искать ошибку будет сложно.
- Если у вас редактируемые через админку правила (человекочитаемые URL, забаненные диапазоны IP и т. п.), то программно редактировать `.htaccess` будет проблематично.

В современных фреймворках и CMS повсеместно используется роутинг через фронт-контроллер. Вот всё, что вам нужно:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Теперь в `index.php` вы будете иметь путь в `$_GET['_route']`, также сохранятся все остальные параметры в запросе GET. Вы можете писать какую вам угодно логику на языке, который вы хорошо знаете и понимаете, используя любые средства вроде доступа к конфигу для получения настроек роутинга и доступа к базе для получения забаненных диапазонов IP.

Если вас не смущает доступ к пути через `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` вместо `$_GET['_route']`, то вы можете упростить `.htaccess` ещё больше, как указано в примечаниях к другому ответу:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]
```

P. S. Каноничный URL обычно достаточно указать в мета-информации страницы. Редиректы из-за отсутствия `/` в конце лишь впустую тратят ресурсы. Также можно воспользоваться [History.replaceState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState), чтобы URL в адресной строке браузера тоже был каноничным.

Comment: можно пример, на js или php?

Comment: @stack-it Если делать роутинг на коленке, а не с помощью библиотек или фреймворков, то я бы сделал его на регулярках. Что-нибудь в духе `[ $controller, $action, $argument ] = preg_match('/^ / (\w+) / (\w+) (?: / (\w+) ) $/x', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); switch ($controller) { case 'home': switch ($action) { case 'index': /*...*/`. Ну или сразу `if (in_array($controller, [ 
'home', /*...*/ ]) && in_array($action, [ 'index', /*...*/ ])) include("controllers/$controller.php");` (при таком подходе валидация строк по белому списку обязательна).

Answer (score 13):

По мотивам вопроса: [Почему съедает слеш в скобочной группе регулярного выражения?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/551332/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%88-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Если использовать вот такое перенаправление:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

То при запросе вида

```
http://localhost//activation-account/$2y$10$Xl40W/SKTOXYcxfCxGszr.9tbd//lNJSVJTpBh4umjWf/9GNMSlJy/loginfiko
```

в переменной `$_GET['_route']` получаем неверный результат:

```
                  activation-account/$2y$10$Xl40W/SKTOXYcxfCxGszr.9tbd/lNJSVJTpBh4umjWf/9GNMSlJy/loginfiko
```

Двойной слеш заменен на одинарный!

Считаю, что более правильно использовать вот такое перенаправление:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ index.php?_route=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Тогда в переменной `$_GET['_route']` получаем результат:

```
                 /activation-account/$2y$10$Xl40W/SKTOXYcxfCxGszr.9tbd//lNJSVJTpBh4umjWf/9GNMSlJy/loginfiko
```

Двойные слеши на месте + второй слеш после host попал в переменную.

**P.S.** Никто не отменял переменную `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` содержимое которой можно распарсить как вам угодно.

Comment: Хм, мне нравится `RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]` — у mod_rewrite забираем ещё больше. :))

Comment: @Squidward, для этого дела я и написал P.S.