# Как сделать страницу x.ru/blog/ вместо x.ru/blog.index.html?

Tags: html, url

Нужно добавить новую страницу на сайт, а точнее

/blog/
Внутри неё потом будет отдельные страницы.

Главный вопрос. Если в корень сайта добавить папку blog, а в неё index.html, то это будет /blog/index.html

Нужно, чтобы ссылка была /blog или /blog/

Как такое сделать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать всё и сразу в mod\_rewrite?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542869/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%91-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b2-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 3):

Для этого необходимо объявить файла index.html индексным. Тогда если в директории имеется файла с таким названием, то обращение к директории будет автоматически загружать данный файл.

Обычно по умолчанию почти на всех серверах index.html назначен в качестве индексного файла, однако в силу каких-то причин это может быть не так. В Web-сервере Apache за индексный файл отвечает директива `DirectoryIndex`. Можно через запятую перечислить несколько индексных файлов (файлы расположенные слева имеют приоритет)

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

В Web-сервере nginx для задания индексного файла используется директива `index`

```
location / {
    index index.html index.php;
}
```