# как убрать .php?id= в конце ссылки

Tags: php, .htaccess

Мне нужно из ссылки page.php?id=1 сделать ссылку page1 тоесть убрать .php?id= и можно ли это сделать с помощю .htaccess

Comment: Делайте это правильно -> http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542869/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%91-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b2-mod-rewrite

Comment: @Visman я не понял как это делается поэтому дайте пожалуйсто ответ именно на мой вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Вам тут надо сделать примерно так

```
RewriteRule ^page([0-9]*)(/?)$ /page.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

То есть мы путь `/page123` преобразуем в `/page.php?id=123` при помощи регулярных выражений в файле .htaccess

Что касается ссылки [на этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542869/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%91-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83-%D0%B2-mod-rewrite), то тут все сделано просто - все пути запросов передаются в виде переменной `_route` в GET запросе в файл index.php. Это дает возможность всю логику маршрутизации реализовать на php - выполнить разбор строки запроса и подключить нужные файлы через `require` или `include`. Такой подход более рационален в том смысле, что лучше сделать единую систему маршрутизации, а не вставлять костыли каждый раз вроде того, что я предложил сейчас

Comment: вы неправильно меня поняли мне нужно наоборот из ссылки page.php?id=123 сделать ссылку page123

Comment: @BedOmar я именно это и сделал - если перейти по ссылке `page123` то эффект будет как если вы перейдете по ссылке `page.php?id=123`. ссылка  `page123`  ничего не значит по умолчанию, так как не указывает на файл (или на папку). В htaccess мы эту ссылку расшифровываем и поэтому она начинает работать

Comment: У меня пишет файл не найден

Comment: @BedOmar постарайтесь давать больше информации о проблеме. И я не могу гарантировать, что все прям таки правильно идеально, тут идея показана как сделать можно. Можете еще поставить условия RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

Answer (score 0):

Пропишите в .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
      RewriteRule ^page([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ page.php?id=$1
      RewriteRule ^page([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ page.php?id=$1
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky +