# Почему съедает слеш в скобочной группе регулярного выражения?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, .htaccess

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteRule ^activation-account/(.+)/login([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ web/index.php?r=registration/activation-register/activation&key_active=$1&key_login=$2 [L]
```

Переходим по ссылке
http://myhost//activation-account/$2y$10$Xl40W/SKTOXYcxfCxGszr.9tbd//lNJSVJTpBh4umjWf/9GNMSlJy/loginfiko

Ловим переменную в php **key_active**

Она возвращает:
$2y$10$Xl40W/SKTOXYcxfCxGszr.9tbd/lNJSVJTpBh4umjWf/9GNMSlJy

То есть на этом промежутке `9tbd/l` убирается слеш а должно быть так `9tbd//l`

Comment: Возможное решение для nginx http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#merge_slashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот рабочий вариант редиректа для Apache:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/*activation-account/(.+)/login(\w+)$
RewriteRule .* web/index.php??r=registration/activation-register/activation&key_active=%1&key_login=%2 [L]
```

В переменных запроса он ни чего не имеет против двойного слеша.

**UPD** + мой ответ на вопрос: [Как сделать всё и сразу в mod_rewrite?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542869/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%91-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83-%D0%B2-mod-rewrite/551401#551401)

Answer (score 4):

Мне кажется, тут проблема не в регулярном выражении а в том как apache обрабатывает URL, а точнее в web-стандартах.

Условно говоря любое количество слешей всегда читается как один слеш. Например  http://myhost/activation-account  http://myhost//activation-account  http://myhost///activation-account и  http://myhost////////////activation-account это путь к одной и той-же странице.

Правельный путь решить эту проблему - использовать urlencode/urldecode или base64

Comment: Тут правильный способ скорее использовать параметры и не выпендриваться