# Как сделать динамический редирект?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Здаствуйте, не могу разобратся как написать редирект для не статических ссылок, то есть ссылки я буду брать с БД и перенаправлять их.
У меня есть `localhost/index.php?id=KMHUd` и я хочу скрыть `index.php?id=` что бы можно было просто написать `localhost/KMHUd`. Подскажите что надо прописать в htaccess?

Cкрипт с [данного вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542869/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%91-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83-%D0%B2-mod-rewrite) не работает:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
    RewriteRule .* index.php?id=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Как сделать редирект для того что бы можно было использовать переменную `$_SERVER` на странице я не знаю.
Файл index.php:

```
    <?php
      $ID = $_GET['id'];
      if($ID)
      {
            try{
                $db = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=mydb", 'admin', 'admin');
                $db->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
                $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM linktable WHERE Substitution=?");
                $query->bindValue(1, $ID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $query->execute();
                $res = $query->fetch();
                if($res != null)
                {
                    $link = 'Location: ' . $res['Link'];
                    //echo "<p>" . $res['Link'];
                    //echo "<p>" . $res['Substitution'];
                    $db  = null;
                    // echo $link;
                    header($link);
                }
                else echo "<p>Not Found!</p>";
            }catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
           $db = null;
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: это не решает мою прблему так как скрипт выше из даного вопроса не работает

Comment: <pre><code>RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule .* index.php?id=%1 [L,QSA]</pre></code>

Comment: А почему он должен работать без соответствующего кода в `index.php`? Вы в своем вопросе указали теги `php` и `.htaccess`, но почему-то я вижу только код из `.htaccess`.

Comment: уже добавил код `index.php` в пост выше.

Comment: После `header($link);` поставьте команду  `exit();`.

Comment: добавил но, это ничего не меняет

Comment: После `$res = $query->fetch();` если добавить `exit(var_dump($res));`, то что в ответ на запрос выведет?

Comment: проблема не в этом, а в редиректе, а точнее в Apache.

Comment: страница без редиректа работает

Answer (score 1):

Используйте  теги для этого, в РНР в header тоже можно делать редиректы...А так через htaccess делать переход используя переменную полученную из БД....не думаю что это вообще возможно.

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, при чем тут БД. Редирект тут самый простой:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^\/index.php\/(\d+)$ /index.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: нет не пренаправляет((

Comment: пробовал так: `RewriteRule ^\/index.html\/(\d+)$ /index.html?id=$1 [QSA]` эффект тот же

Comment: А где находится этот index.php - , может, нужно убрать ^ знак в начале?

Comment: нет, нечего не поменялось(