# mod_rewrite не срабатывает capture после кириллицы в пути

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, кириллица, path

Запрос:

```
http://lounger.ru/things/jacket/222
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^/?things/[a-z]*/([0-9]*)$ /pages/item/item\.html?id=$1 [R]
```

попадаем по ддресу:

```
http://lounger.ru/pages/item/item.html?id=222
```

все вышеперечисленное работает.. теперь хочу перевести на руский

Запрос:

```
http://lounger.ru/вещи/куртка/222
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^/?вещи/[а-я]*/(.*)$ /pages/item/item\.html?id=$1 [R]
```

попадаем сюда:

```
http://lounger.ru/вещи/куртка/222
```

- то есть редирект не сработал. Есть подозрение, что [а-я]* и (.*)$ не срабатывает после кириллицы

сама по себе кириллица как-то реаигирует, ибо:

Запрос:

```
http://lounger.ru/вещи/
```

htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^/?вещи/ /pages/item/item\.html?id=$1 [R]
```

попадаем сюда:

```
http://lounger.ru/pages/item/item.html?id=
```

Comment: А вы делайте так `RewriteRule ^/?вещи/[^/]+/(.*)$ /pages/item/item\.html?id=$1 [R]`, а лучше так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542869/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%91-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b2-mod-rewrite

Comment: работает! попробую теперь понять как это работает..