# ЧПУ для мобильной и полной версии сайта в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, чпу, мобильная-разработка

Коллеги!
Помогите решить вопрос с ЧПУ на музыкальном сайте.

ссылка выглядит так: site.ru/mp3/song/14/25
14 - id песни
25 - id исполнителя

в htaccess два кода - ЧПУ для полной версии и для мобильной версии сайта.
кусок кода в htaccess следующий:

```
# ЧПУ MP3-мобильная версия и редирект --РАБОЧИЙ--
RewriteRule ^mp3/song/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /mp3/msong.php?id=$1&artist_id=$2&norec [L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+)&artist_id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^mp3/msong.php$ /mp3/song/%1/%2/? [L,R=301]

# ЧПУ mp3 полная версия и редирект (--ПРОБНЫЙ--)
RewriteRule ^mp3/song/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /mp3/song.php?id=$1&artist_id=$2&norec [L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+)&artist_id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^mp3/song.php$ /mp3/song/%1/%2/? [L,R=301]
```

вся суть в четвёртой строке в обоих кусочках кода

**ЗАДАЧА**: как сделать чтобы **адрес отдавался один и тот же**, НО чтобы страницы были разные (т.е. mp3/msong.php - моб.версия, и mp3/song.php - полная версия), и выдавались фактически разные вёрстки - отдельно для моб. и десктопов (обе вёрстки давно готовы и успешно функционируют)? Адрес должен быть такой: **site.ru/mp3/song/14/25** - для обоих версий сайта.

Сейчас выдаётся только для мобильных устройств, т.к. кусок кода для моб.весрии стоит выше.
Или можно как-то объединить эти строки? наподобие: RewriteRule ^mp3/msong.php **OR** mp3/song.php$ /mp3/song/%1/%2/? [L,R=301] - если такое вообще существует (операторы OR и AND в htaccess)

Comment: Добавляйте какие-то различия в адресную строку, в куки, добавляйте определение юзерагента, так как по другому разделение не получить, если условия в правилах одинаковые.

Comment: разделение по юзерагенту прописано в PHP.

Comment: отдать один и тот же адрес не получится?

Comment: Раз у вас в php уже прописано разделение по юзерагенту, то зачем вы с .htaccess мучаетесь? Делайте все в php по такому принципу http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542869/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%91-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b2-mod-rewrite

Comment: через htaccess - буквально пару символов исправить, максимум - две строчки. А в php - писать и писать.

Comment: нашёл вариант - через регулярку, но изменений нет:     RewriteRule ^mp3/(song.php|msong.php)$