# Как сделать путь на сайте без раcширения (.html, .php)

Tags: php, api, url, чпу

Очень часто вижу что на сайтах после перехода на страницу нет расширения страницы в адресной строке.
Например, [ruSO Помощь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help), адрес выглядит именно `https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help`, а не `https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help.php` или `https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help.html`. Как именно это делается? И что это за технология?

Плюс сразу же вопрос из той же оперы, но про `api` сайта. К примеру возьму Вконтакте. Вызов метода выглядит следующим образом:
`https://api.vk.com/method/METHOD_NAME?PARAMETERS&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&v=V`
То есть после `METHOD_NAME` нет `.php`, а на некоторых других сайтах есть. Плюс я еще встречал что-то вроде `METHOD_NAME#...` Что же это все означает и как реализовывается? И преимущества какие у каждого?

---

**UPD**

Сделал, получилось. Сервер `apache`

Сделал следующим образом:

`index.php` - в корне, остальные страницы в папке `pages`
Моя проблема с `headers already sent by...` решилась следующим образом.
Я неправильно подошел к решению задачи, в файл `index.php` нужно лишь обрабатывать перенаправления, а я запихнул туда содержимое главной страницы.
В `.htaccess` написал в начале следующее:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Затем в файле `index.php`:

```
<?php
    $url = explode('/',strtolower(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1)));

    switch($url[0]) {
        case '': { //Если пусто в адресе, то направляем на главную
            include 'pages/main_page.php';
            break;
        }
        case 'news':{
            include 'pages/news_page.php';
            break;
        }
        case 'buy':{
            include 'pages/my_buy_page.php';
            break;
        }
        case 'somepage':{
            include 'pages/somepage.php';
            break;
        }
    }
?>
```

Интересно то, что папка `includes` находится на одном уровне с папкой `pages`, `include` в файле например `pages/news_page.php` нужно писать без `../`, то есть просто `include ('includes/foobar.php');`

Все работает, спасибо @Stanislav, за подсказку

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Для реализации ЧПУ (человеко-понятный урл), а именно так называются понятные адреса, нужно определиться, что у вас за сервер: nginx или apache.

А) Если у вас apache, то достаточно разместить файл .htaccess с необходимыми параметрами в корне сайта, при этом, так же, должен быть включен mod_rewrite (в конфиге апача).

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

А в коде самого сайта вам нужно сделать систему роутинга, т.е. разбор полученных путей.

Чисто в качестве примера могу привести:

**index.php**

```
<?php

$_GET['url'] = strtolower($_GET['url']);

switch($_GET['url']) {
    case '': {
        echo 'INDEX';
        break;
    }
    case 'news':{
        echo 'NEWS';
        break;
    }
}
```

Если вы теперь введете в адресной строке *http://mysite.local* , то получите **INDEX** , а если *http://mysite.local/news* , то получите **NEWS**.

Б) Если у вас nginx, то все условия задаются непосредственно в конфиге для сайта. Например, так:

```
location / {
    index  index.html index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

В этом случае (кстати и для случая А) можно использовать примерно такой вариант работы для **index.php**:

```
<?php

$url = explode('/',strtolower(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1)));

switch($url[0]) {
    case '': {
        echo 'INDEX';
        break;
    }
    case 'news':{
        echo 'NEWS';
        break;
    }
}
```

2. Для реализации API вы можете придумывать что хотите, но я бы рекомендовал придерживаться стандарта REST. Подробнее можете поискать в Google или Yandex , например по словосочетанию "RESTful API".

Comment: С аппачем тоже лучше данные брать из `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, а то могут ошибки быть со слешами в адресе: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542869/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%91-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b2-mod-rewrite/551401#551401

Comment: Да, я это и написал: *В этом случае (**кстати и для случая А**) можно использовать примерно такой вариант работы*

Comment: У меня `apache`. Как мне по кейсам страницу другую загружать? include выдает что `headers already sent by ...`

Comment: @Herrgott, значит у вас какая-то информация отправляется раньше отсылки заголовков. Смотрите лишние пробелы, echo вывод, UTF-8 with BOM. Тут куча вопросов и ответов https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=headers+already+sent+by