# Самый простой ЧПУ

Tags: php, html, чпу

Есть лендинг с 2 страницами index.html и en.html. Как сделать самый простой ЧПУ чтоб на английской  версии лендинга был УРЛ типа /en

Comment: Что именно не получается?

Answer (score 1):

Файл `.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
#Don't favicon!
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^favicon\.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Теперь надо парсить `$_SERVER['REQUEST_STRING'];` и передавать нужные параметры скрипту который это все дело обрабатывает, или можна просто брать `$_GET['param']`.

`$_GET['param']` - это файл который вы должны подключить

Примерно вот так:

```
switch ($_GET['param']) {
    case 'param_1': //или 'index'
     // выполняем нужные функции/методы
    break;
   case 'param_2':
     // выполняем нужные функции/методы
    break;
}
```

Comment: Кто плюсует ответ с ошибкой? :)

Comment: @Visman почему же с ошибкой? Пока что у меня все работает:)

Comment: Откуда у вас взялся `$_GET['param']`?

Comment: @Visman наверное из строки запроса. Возможно вы жалуетесь на `RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?$1 [L,QSA]` ?) Должно быть `RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?view$1 [L,QSA]` и тогда уже будет `$_GET['param']`. Так?

Comment: Нет, не так. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/567782/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%80%D0%B0c%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-html-php/#567790