# 301 редирект на одном домене

Tags: .htaccess, редирект, http-status-code-301

Всем привет. Я переношу сайт на новый движок и адреса страниц не сохранить. Решил сделать 301 редирект
На старом сайте страница имела вид http://site.ru/?a=category&b=1
На новом http://site.ru/category 
Домен один и тот же
Спасибо большое всем кто откликнется

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать всё и сразу в mod\_rewrite?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542869/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%91-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b2-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} a=([^&]*)[NC]
RewriteRule .* /%1? [R=301,L]
```

Для работы с GET параметрами используется %{QUERY_STRING}. если в параметрах есть параметр "а", мы запоминает его значение и используем в новом урле (запись %1).

- NC   Регистронезависимая проверка
- R=301    Будет редирект с кодом 301,  можно указать другой код
- L    Это последнее правило, больше не применять правил преобразований
- в конце знак "?" - Он нам нужен, чтобы отсечь исходные GET параметры, иначе получим  http://site.ru/category?a=category&b=1

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Comment: Ваше правило написано с ошибкой. Конечный URL будет вида `http://site.ru/category&b=1`, а автор явно хотел не этого. Правильно будет вместо `(.*)` использовать `([^&]*)`. Исправьте свой ответ, пожалуйста.

Comment: @VenZell исправил