# .htaccess перенаправлени

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

У меня реализована модель MVC, когда идет запрос, .htaccess перенаправляет на папку webroot. Как сделать что б при определенном запросе(site.com/folder) перенаправляло на другую папку(folder)?
Вот мой .htaccess который лежит в корне проекта.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
    AddDefaultCharset utf-8
</IfModule>
```

Comment: А вы приммер вашего htaccess не хотите привести?

Comment: @Naumov Добавил

Comment: @niksib, если вам помог мой ответ, пожалуйста, проголосуйте за него и отметьте как верный.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать всё и сразу в mod\_rewrite?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542869/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%91-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b2-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По-хорошему, достаточно исключить данный URL из вашего роутинга и ловить запрос уже на месте в нужной папке. Исключить URL можно так:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/    
    RewriteRule ^$ webroot/ [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/
    RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
    AddDefaultCharset utf-8
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Так выдает ошибку

Comment: @niksib Какую ошибку?

Comment: Server error!
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.
Error 500

Comment: вот такую - "Server error! The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script. Error 500 "

Comment: @niksib Везде или по указанному url?

Comment: везде выдает такую ошибку

Comment: @niksib, я исправил опечатку, пожалуйста, попробуйте еще раз

Comment: Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@dummy-host.example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Теперь вот такая ошибка

Comment: @niksib, а теперь на всем сайте или только по указанному URL?

Comment: Так же на всем сайте

Comment: @niksib, в указанном коде больше нет синтаксических ошибок. Это все содержимое вашего .htaccess?

Comment: Тот который лежит в корне проекта, да это все содержимое.

Comment: А есть ли .htaccess в папке `/folder/`? И каково его содержимое?

Comment: .htaccess в папке /folder нету

Comment: @niksib, возможно, спрошу глупость, но когда удаляете строчки вот эти: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/` все работает?

Comment: Да, все работает

Comment: Все работает, я не тот .htaccess открыл, спасибо большое