# Настроить переход по ссылкам и добавить redirect в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Необходимо настроить 301 редирект с одной страницы на другую.

В .htaccess написан следующий код:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

php_flag display_errors off
php_value error_reporting 2047
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

#DirectoryIndex /index.php
#ErrorDocument 500 /index.php
#ErrorDocument 401 /index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404
ErrorDocument 403 /error/403
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /


#слеш
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[A-Za-z0-9]+$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

#Избавление от лишних слешей
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]


#чпу
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /index.php?request=$1 [L]

#без www на www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.мой_сайт\.ru [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.мой_сайт.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

В url ссылка получается типа: `http://мой_сайт.ru/?request=назва_раздела`

Как избавиться от `?request=` и добавить 301 редирект?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать всё и сразу в mod\_rewrite?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542869/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%91-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b2-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 1):

```
#чпу
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /index.php?request=$1 [L]
```

Заменить на

```
#чпу
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

Comment: Добавляю 

    Redirect 301 /apple/ http://www.мой_сайт.ru/articles/

Редирект не происходит

Comment: Определитесь, на какой вопрос Вам требуется ответ. "Как избавиться от ..." или "Как сделать редирект". Если требуется два ответа - создайте отдельный вопрос. Также, если мой ответ Вам помог избавиться от "?request=", прошу отметить его как _верный_

Comment: В том то и проблема, что нужно сделать 301 редирект, при этом, чтобы не выводился "?request="