# Как получить произвольное количество GET параметров через MOD_REWRITE?

Tags: .htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

Есть ссылки вида:

```
www.site.ru/city123
www.site.ru/city123/type54/project1198
www.site.ru/project1198/type54/
```

Иными словами, количество параметров (буквы+цифры) может быть произвольным, а может и вообще не быть.
вот такой код, помогает получить только первую пару буквы+цифры

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]*)([0-9]*)/*$ index.php?$1=$2%{QUERY_STRING}
```

На выходе имею:

```
$_GET[city] => 123
```

Как в этом случае получить все GET параметры, если их количество может быть произвольным либо не быть вовсе?

Answer (score 0):

Через .htaccess таким способом можно получить только 4 параметра, так как всего на группы с обратной связью выделено 9 позиций ($1 - $9) + $0 - вся строка запроса.

Пример

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)(\d+)/?$ index.php?$1=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)(\d+)/([a-z]+)(\d+)/?$ index.php?$1=$2&$3=$4 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)(\d+)/([a-z]+)(\d+)/([a-z]+)(\d+)/?$ index.php?$1=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)(\d+)/([a-z]+)(\d+)/([a-z]+)(\d+)/([a-z]+)(\d+)/?$ index.php?$1=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8 [L,QSA]
```

[Правильнее](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542869/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%91-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83-%D0%B2-mod-rewrite) будет переадресовать запросы такого вида в роутер написаный на php, который будет разбирать строку запроса и формировать переменные на ее основе: