# Каким образом сделать ЧПУ для подразделов

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, чпу

Здравствуйте.
Есть каталог, в котором есть Главные разделы и подразделы.

Ссылки на главные разделы имеют вид:

> **сайт/section/games**
>
> **сайт/section/images**
>
> **сайт/section/doc**

Правило в .htaccess для них:

```
RewriteRule ^section\/(.+)$ modules/section.php?url=$1
```

Вопрос: Каким образом сделать ссылки на вложенные разделы вида:

> `сайт/games/1`

где **1** - id подраздела.

Ссылка *games*  создается автоматически при создании раздела, поэтому для каждого раздела прописывать правило в .htaccess не вариант.
Нужно какое-то универсальное решение.

Буду благодарен за полезную информацию.

Comment: Не надо делать "ЧПУ для подразделов". Надо сделать ЧПУ для всего сайта, а весь остальной роутинг делать на РНР.

Comment: Общий принцип https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542869/

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте так (после правила для section):

`RewriteRule ^(.+)\/([0-9]+)$ modules/index.php?category=$1&id=$2`

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.