# Перенаправление страниц

Tags: .htaccess

Как настроить перенаправление для страниц сайта с любым количеством слешей на конце на соответствующие с одним слешем. Т.е со страницы `http:\\site.ru\master\\\\` на страницу `http:\\site.ru\master\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
# если в запросе есть как минимум два слэша подряд,
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //
# то сделать 301 редирект страницы на саму себя :)
RewriteRule .* /$0 [R=301,L]
```

Почему это работает?
Потому что Apache (и IIS) игнорирует дублирующие слэши в строке запроса и если в `%{THE_REQUEST}` они все еще присутствуют, то в `RewriteRule` их уже нет ([сопутствующая проблема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/551401/186083)).

Решение взято от сюда https://toster.ru/q/43614

**P.S.** Решение заменяет мульти-слэши в любом месте url, а не только в конце!