# php склеить два "/" в url странице

Tags: php, url

```
$url = "https://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
if($url != preg_replace('/([^:])(\/{2,})/', '$1/', $url)){
    header('Location: '. preg_replace('/([^:])(\/{2,})/', '$1/', $url), true, 301);
  exit();
}
```

Задача склеить все "/", которые идут подряд и сделать редирект на правильный адрес.
Подскажите, что не так?

Comment: заменить на `/$1`а  не `/$1` ?

Comment: либо `(?<!:)(\/{2,})` заменять на `/`

Comment: что-то я смешное написал в первом комменте :D а что не так то? вроде заменяет ведь все исправно? не ясно правда, зачем вы клеите весь url, и потом усложняете замену, если можно было сделать замену только в части request_uri. да и делать такое пожалуй надо на уровне апача, а не пхп.

Comment: Решение через .htaccess https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/600073/186083

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так переписать:

```
$url = "https://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$fixed_url = preg_replace('/([^:])(\/{2,})/', '$1/', $url);
if($url != $fixed_url){
    header('Location: '. $fixed_url, true, 301);
  exit();
}
```

Comment: дак что принципиально поменялось в данном коде? в чем была ошибка? я вот пока что вижу лишнюю скобку в `header`

Comment: Спасибо, teran. Переделал.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]