# Как сделать редирект url'а с %2F через htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Url такого вида

```
/registr/%2Fpersonal%2Forder%2Fmake%2F
```

нужно редиректить через htaccess.
Правило вида

```
RewriteRule ^/registr/%2Fpersonal%2Forder%2Fmake%2F$  https://site.com/personal/order/make/  [R=301,L]
```

htaccess не понимает.
Не понимает также и такого вида

```
/registr//personal/order/make/
```

Как сделать редрект?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Перенаправление страниц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/600028/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86)

Comment: Поставим вопрос иначе. Подобный url как редиректить - personal%2Forder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В конфиг **apache** добавьте в описание `VirtualHost` [директиву](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes)

```
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
```

После этого можете использовать редирект

```
RewriteRule ^registr/%2Fpersonal%2Forder%2Fmake%2F$  https://site.com/personal/order/make/  [R=301,L]
```

P.S. **Ведущий слеш удален!**

**UPD** Вариант 2:

Использовать директиву

```
AllowEncodedSlashes On
```

И .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
# если в запросе есть как минимум два слэша подряд,
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} // [OR]
# или кодированный слеш
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} %2F
# то сделать 301 редирект страницы на саму себя :)
RewriteRule .* /$0 [R=301,L]
```

`%2F` будут заменены на слеши и множественные слеши будут заменены на одинарные.

Comment: К сожалению, с двойным слешем не работает (registr/%2F), если оставить registr%2F, то все хорошо.

Comment: @Сергей, это разные ссылки: `registr/%2F` и `registr%2F` Для каждой нужно свое правило. Либо общее для замены всех `%2F` на `/`, но тут получится циклический редирект с заменами. Может вам стоит в движке сайта реализовать одномоментную замену всех `%2F` и один редирект после этого. Или вообще такие ссылки признать ошибочными и возвращать 404 статус. Откуда они у вас берутся?

Comment: Пока непонятно, откуда они берутся и как формируются. Чтобы пофиксить в движке сайта, даже не знаю, сколько времени уйдет. Проше сделать редирект.

Comment: Это идет переброс сюда после успешной авторизации (/registr/%2Fpersonal%2Forder%2Fmake%2F). Это если по https. Если ту же операцию проделать по http, то перебрасывает на /personal/order/make/, т.е. все красиво.

Comment: @Сергей, предложил вам второй вариант решения. Если у вас в .htaceess есть другие правила, то они должны стоять ниже данного редиректа!

Comment: Супер! Спасибо большое!

Comment: А как сделать, чтоб она редиректилась не на саму себя а на нужный URL?

Comment: Пока стоит двойной редирект - вначале на саму себя, а затем на нужный. Но, мне кажется, можно проще.

Comment: Появилась еще проблема - на сервере nginx и нет настроек VirtualHost, как в апаче (на локальном у меня). Непонятно куда добавить директиву AllowEncodedSlashes On.

Comment: @Сергей, в nginx все по другому, это не apache. Создавайте новый вопрос для него.