# Каким образом передать несколько GET по ЧПУ ссылке

Tags: php, .htaccess

Здравствуйте. В .htaccess у меня есть правило:

> RewriteRule ^category/(.+)$ modules/category.php?id=$1

Благодаря ему ссылки я получаю вида **/category/5** , где *5* - id нужного мне раздела из базы данных, его я потом получаю из `$_GET['id']` и делаю по нему выборку из базу.

Вопрос, каким образом мне сделать ссылки, чтобы были вида **/gorod/name** , где *gorod* и *name* , были бы $_GET значениями, то есть, если без ЧПУ то ссылка такая есть `modules/category.php?id=gorod&pod=name`

Буду благодарен за любую полезную информацию.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(.+)$ modules/category.php?id=$1&pod=$2
```

Comment: если я добавляю это правило, все остальные перестают работать((

Comment: например это уже не работает `RewriteRule ^sign-up modules/reg.php [L,QSA]` - отвечает  **not found**

Comment: то есть получается все эти ссылки уже ведут на modules/category.php

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, `gorod/name/and/noname/or/second/city/` тоже отлично пропускает.

Comment: @Денис Логично. А как Вы собрались отличать действие sign-up от города sign-up? Попробуйте это правило добавить последним.

Comment: вот в этом то и загвоздка... как быть?

Comment: @Денис, вот так http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/542869/186083

Comment: @Денис Как быть? Определиться чего хочется. Чтобы первым шел город или команда. Может имеет смысл сделать так `/cities/gorod/name`?

Comment: @Visman Так и должно быть. Автор хотел именно этого. Может у автора город  такой `name/and/noname/or/second/city/`?