# Необычный постраничный 301 редирект в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Подскажите пожалуйста надо в htaccess сделать 301 редирект со всех страниц домена site.ru вида

[http://www.site.ru/?id=22&keyword=значение+произвольное](http://www.site.ru/?id=22&keyword=%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5)

на

[http://site2.com/?id22&keyword=значение+произвольное](http://site2.com/?id22&keyword=%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5)

Самое главное - убрать знак равно из id=22 на новом домене. Скорее всего, надо как-то модифицировать постраничный 301 редирект. Спасибо!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.ru$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.ru$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать через mod_rewrite через условие RewriteCond, проверяющее QUERY_STRING. Добавьте перед существующим правилом (сразу после `RewriteEngine On`) такой код:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.ru$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.ru$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots.*
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)(&keyword=.*)
RewriteRule ^$ http://site2.com/?id%1%2 [R=301,L]

# ... потом ваше существующее правило:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.ru$ [OR,NC]
...
```

Что здесь происходит:

1. `RewriteCond` проверяет QUERY_STRING на соответствие регулярному выражению.
2. Значения в скобках в регулярном выражении попадают в переменные `%1` и `%2`. В `%1` попадает число из `id`. В `%2` попадает все что после `id`.
3. `RewriteRule` подставляет эти переменные в нужные места запроса.

Несмотря на то, что это (и еще много чего) можно сделать через mod_rewrite, я рекомендую рассмотреть возможность написать механизм редиректа на движке вашего сайта, а не в .htaccess. Аргументы в пользу такого варианта приведены в [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542869/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%91-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83-%D0%B2-mod-rewrite).