# Переадресация всех сылок с окончанием .pdf

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, .htaccess

Здравствуйте, нужно чтобы ссылки mysite.ru/example.pdf перенаправлял  mysite.ru/docs/example.pdf. PDF много и общего в названиях нет. Как реализавать что бы все pdf запрошеные в корне пренаправляло в docs

Comment: А как ты перенаправляешь на mysite.ru/example.pdf

Comment: example.pdf лежит в docs папке?

Comment: @ЮраПетров Был старый сайт, в котором все лежало в корне. Старые ссылки используются на других ресурсах, поэтому нужно перенаправить людей на новый адрес.

Comment: @ЮраПетров Да, сейчас лежат.

Comment: [Как сделать всё и сразу в mod_rewrite?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542869/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%91-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b2-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правило для .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+).pdf /docs/$1.pdf [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Работает!