# ЧПУ на mod rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, чпу

Стоит задача внедрения ЧПУ на сайт и возникла проблема с get запросами.

Есть url строка http://www.mysite.com/proizvoditel?id=4, ее нужно преобразовать в http://www.mysite.com/proizvoditel/4

Вот код файла .htaccess

```
RewriteBase / 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/542870/200260

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй вот так:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=4$
RewriteRule ^(proizvoditel)$ /$1/4? [R=301, L]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
RewriteRule ^proizvoditel/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)(/?)$ index.php?do=proizvoditel&id=$1
```