# ('%EF%BB%BF' , '%C2%A0') Что это за символы и как их удалить из url?

Tags: php, строки, utf-8, unicode

Помогите пожалуйста решить.

```
1) var_dump('%EF%BB%BF'); //string(3) ""

2) var_dump('%C2%A0'); // string(2) " "
```

Первый вроде пустая строка,как может быть результат `var_dum = string(3)` "".

Другого объяснения как юникод я не знаю.Походу эти (utf-8) невидимые символы и есть.

Самый простой вариант

```
var_dump(explode('%', 'aaa%EF%BB%BF')[0]);
```

Но насколько правильно поступать таким образом я не уверен

Если это так то надо учесть что может быть этот пробел под другой кодировкой выглядит иначе и как можно очистить от него строку ?

Comment: Вам может пригодиться: [Как сделать всё и сразу в mod_rewrite?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542869/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%91-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b2-mod-rewrite)

Comment: @NickVolynkin вопрос в том что у меня все нормально настроено,Пробелы нормально удаляются.Но эти нет,я не знаю почему пробелы ввиде символов не удаляются

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176904/php-how-to-remove-all-non-printable-characters-in-a-string

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`%EF%BB%BF` - **BOM** -  Byte Order Mark для Unicode.
`%C2%A0` - Utf-8 non breaking space

> В таком формате Вы видите их в URL, в php же они приходят как:
>
> - `%EF%BB%BF` => pack("CCC",0xef,0xbb,0xbf)
> - `%C2%A0` => pack("CC",0xc2,0xa0)
>
> Ну, или проще:
>   `urldecode('%C2%A0')`
>
> Именно так их и нужно проверять.
>
> В этом вашем примере в исходной строке все символы **печатные**:
>   `var_dump(explode('%', 'aaa%EF%BB%BF')[0]);`

Удалить можно так:

```
function removeBOM($str=""){
    if(substr($str, 0,3) == pack("CCC",0xef,0xbb,0xbf)) {
            $str=substr($str, 3);
    }
    return $str;
}
```

И так:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\xA0/u', '', 'A'.pack("CC",0xc2,0xa0).'B');
```

Удалить все непечатаемые символы:

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^[:print:]]/', '', $str);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/30K7s)

```
var_dump(preg_replace('/\xA0/u', '', urldecode("Word%C2%A0Word"))); // WordWord
var_dump(preg_replace('/[^[:print:]]/', '', urldecode("%EF%BB%BFWord%C2%A0Word"))); // WordWord
```

Comment: про BOM метку согласен , а вот C2A0 вроде бы [Слог Хангыль syuk U+C2A0](https://unicode-table.com/ru/C2A0/) PS:  %00%C2%00%A0 в UTF8 или %00%A0 вот  unicode non-breaking space.

Comment: Это в `UTF-16BE`. [No-Break Space U+00A0](https://unicode-table.com/en/00A0/) Смотреть секцию Кодировка, строка UTF-8

Comment: У меня не удаляет  var_dump(preg_replace('/\xA0/u', '', '%EF%BB%BF')); = string(9) "%EF%BB%BF"

Comment: Во первых, строка из девяти байт - вообще не то, что было в вопросе. Во вторых, эта регулярка для удаления неразрывного пробела.

Comment: @Sergey, прочтите в ответе выделенный текст

Comment: Не помогло  - preg_replace('/[^[:print:]]/u', '', urldecode($uri),//string(3) "" ,
А этот даже не знаю как использовать - preg_replace('/\xA0/u', '', 'A'.pack("CC",0xc2,0xa0).'B').

Comment: [Демонстрация](https://3v4l.org/30K7s)

Comment: Demo помогло понять.Спасибо

Comment: Просто надо было сразу сюда писать ответ.Если вас не затруднит то подредактируйте свой ответ

Answer (score 3):

Перевод [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176904/php-how-to-remove-all-non-printable-characters-in-a-string/1176923#1176923)

### 7-битный ASCII?

Если вы вдруг оказались в 1963 году, и всего лишь хотите использовать печатные символы 7-битного ASCII, то нужно всего лишь удалить все символы в диапазоне кодов 0-31 и 127-255:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F-\xFF]/', '', $string);
```

### 8-битный расширенный ASCII?

В 1963 вам не понравилось и вы переместились в восьмидесятые и столкнулись с 8-битным ASCII, в котором символы 128-255 являются обычными, отображаемыми, символами. Тогда вам нужно лишь слегка скорректировать строку замены и удалять символы 0-31 и 127:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/', '', $string);
```

### UTF-8?

Добро пожаловать в 21 век! Если ваша строка является строкой UTF-8, то вам придется использовать  [модификатор](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) `\u`:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/u', '', $string);
```

Вы просто удаляете символы 0-31 и 127. Данная конструкция будет работать как для UTF-8, так и для 8-битного ASCII, так как второе является подмножеством первого и они обе имеют [одни и те же диапазоны управляющих символов](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm). Откровенно говоря, такая конструкция будет работать и без `/u`, но он сделает вашу жизнь легче, если вам будет необходимо удалять и какие либо другие символы...

Если же вы имеете дело в Unicode, то в нем [очень много непечатных символов](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770117/what-is-the-range-of-unicode-printable-characters), но давайте рассмотрим один, самый часто употребимый: [NO-BREAK SPACE (U+00A0)](https://unicode-table.com/en/00A0/)

В строке UTF-8, он может быть представлен как `0xC2A0`. Соответственно вам будет необходимо искать и удалять эту последовательность символов, но, если вы использовали модификатор `/u`, вы можете просто указать `\xA0`:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F\xA0]/u', '', $string);
```

### Бонус: а что если str_replace?

preg_replace крайне эффективен, но если вам необходимо обработать большое количество текста, то более производительным будет использовать str_replace с указанием ему массива символов:

```
//задаем массив, который будем использовать во всех своих операциях замены
$badchar=array(
    // Управляющие символы
    chr(0), chr(1), chr(2), chr(3), chr(4), chr(5), chr(6), chr(7), chr(8), chr(9), chr(10),
    chr(11), chr(12), chr(13), chr(14), chr(15), chr(16), chr(17), chr(18), chr(19), chr(20),
    chr(21), chr(22), chr(23), chr(24), chr(25), chr(26), chr(27), chr(28), chr(29), chr(30),
    chr(31),
    // Непечатные символы
    chr(127)
);

//Удаляем нежелательные символы
$str2 = str_replace($badchar, '', $str);
```

Интуитивно кажется, что данный подход будет работать сильно быстрее, но давайте проведем тесты. Создадим набор тестовых строк различной длины и содержания и проверим скорость работы (использовался PHP 7.0.12):

```
     2 chars str_replace     5.3439ms preg_replace     2.9919ms preg_replace is 44.01% faster
     4 chars str_replace     6.0701ms preg_replace     1.4119ms preg_replace is 76.74% faster
     8 chars str_replace     5.8119ms preg_replace     2.0721ms preg_replace is 64.35% faster
    16 chars str_replace     6.0401ms preg_replace     2.1980ms preg_replace is 63.61% faster
    32 chars str_replace     6.0320ms preg_replace     2.6770ms preg_replace is 55.62% faster
    64 chars str_replace     7.4198ms preg_replace     4.4160ms preg_replace is 40.48% faster
   128 chars str_replace    12.7239ms preg_replace     7.5412ms preg_replace is 40.73% faster
   256 chars str_replace    19.8820ms preg_replace    17.1330ms preg_replace is 13.83% faster
   512 chars str_replace    34.3399ms preg_replace    34.0221ms preg_replace is  0.93% faster
  1024 chars str_replace    57.1141ms preg_replace    67.0300ms str_replace  is 14.79% faster
  2048 chars str_replace    94.7111ms preg_replace   123.3189ms str_replace  is 23.20% faster
  4096 chars str_replace   227.7029ms preg_replace   258.3771ms str_replace  is 11.87% faster
  8192 chars str_replace   506.3410ms preg_replace   555.6269ms str_replace  is  8.87% faster
 16384 chars str_replace  1116.8811ms preg_replace  1098.0589ms preg_replace is  1.69% faster
 32768 chars str_replace  2299.3128ms preg_replace  2222.8632ms preg_replace is  3.32% faster
```

Замеры производились для 10.000 итераций. Тут очень интересно посмотреть на относительные различия. Для строк длиной до 512 символов со значительным отрывом побеждает preg_replace. В диапазоне 1-8kb разница нивелируется.

Интересный результат, не правда ли? Но в любом случае не стоит всецело полагаться на мои тесты, так как на ваших конкретных данных все может быть ровно наоборот.

Comment: Вы пробовали эти премьеры запустить вот так  var_dump(preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/', '', '%EF%BB%BF')); , или любой другой.У меня ни чего не происходит  :(

Comment: Там как бы и вопрос мягко говоря другой, может стоит и вопрос перевести, переместив ответ туда?

Comment: 1) preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F\xA0]/u', '', urldecode($uri),
2) preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/u', '', urldecode($uri)

Не удаляются, а вопрос был как удалить .
Может я неправильно все понял ,щас пытаюсь разобраться

Comment: @vp_arth ну в изначальном варианте вопроса про удаление этих символов было. А так то мне просто очень ответ понравился, вот и решил перевести :)

Comment: Ответ хороший и нужный, я просто говорю, что ему, возможно, нужен более релевантный вопрос, который несложно создать.

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле, посмотрите в сторону расширения [INTL](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.intl.php)

Там есть, например, [такое](http://php.net/manual/ru/intlchar.isprint.php)

> IntlChar::isprint — Проверяет, является ли симвом отображаемым