# Как правильно применить сразу два регулярных выражения ко всем а href?

Tags: php, html, регулярные-выражения, utf-8

**В итоге что хочу сделать : Мне нужно очистить все мои ссылки от UTF-8-ВОМ символов.**

Ребята из здешнего СО помогли мне написать несколько регулярок

```
//Удаляет BOM символы из urls
$buffer = preg_replace('/[^[:print:]]/', '', $buffer);
```

[Обсуждение про UTF-8-BOM символы можно посмотреть тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/621569/efbbbf-c2a0-%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7-url)

```
//находит все открывающие tags <а ...> с атрибутами и пока что заменяет на те же значения.
//Я так понял действует только с двойными кавычками
$buffer = preg_replace('/<a(.*?)href="(.*?)"(.*?)>/','<a$1href="$2"$3>',$buffer);
```

Теперь мне надо регулярку для удаления **BOM** символов применить к `<а href`. Тоесть к `$2`

```
$buffer=<<<HTML
    AAA
    <a href="http://www.newsru.com/sport/10feb2017/zozu.html%EF%BB%BF">AAA</a>
    <div>TEXT</div>
    AAA
    <a href="http://www.newsru.com/sport/10feb2017/zozu.html%EF%BB%BF">AAA</a>
    <div>TEXT</div>
        <hr/>
HTML;

echo $buffer;

$buffer = preg_replace('/<a(.*?)href="(.*?)"(.*?)>/','<a$1href="'.preg_replace('/[^[:print:]]/', '', '$2').'"$3>',$buffer);
$buffer = preg_replace("/<a(.*?)href='(.*?)'(.*?)>/",'<a$1href="'.preg_replace('/[^[:print:]]/', '', '$2').'"$3>',$buffer);

echo $buffer;
```

Правильно ли я его применяю ?Если нет то прошу написать рабочий вариант.И если возможно подкорректировать код.Ведь я два раза применяю его к одиночным и двойным кавичкам.

Спасибо.

Comment: строки с `\xA0` не нужны, `[^[:print:]]` их вырезает.

Comment: Самый интересный вопрос, откуда берутся эти ссылки, откуда в них могут быть непечатные символы?

Comment: @vp_arth  1 ) %EF%BB%BF, 2 ) %C2%A0
[^[:print:]] вырезает одно из них . Я проверял

Comment: Вместо кавычек можно написать `[\'\"]`

Comment: Вернитесь в Demo, и посмотрите на вторую строку.

Comment: @vp_arth Есть люди у которых в редакторах кодировка стоит utf-8-boom,я так думаю из за этого. Они в кодировках не шарят.А им чо говори чо неговори.По одному месту :)

Comment: @vp_arth Я понял и поправил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться функцией [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

```
$url = urldecode("http://example.org/%EF%BB%BFWord/%C2%A0Word");
$buffer = <<<HTML
<body>
  <a href="$url?q=1">Url 1</a>
  <a href="$url?q=2">Url 2</a>
  <a href='$url?q=3'>Url 3</a>
</body>
HTML;

$buffer = preg_replace_callback(
    '/<a(.*?)href=[\'"](.*?)[\'"](.*?)>/',
    function ($matches) {
      return "<a{$matches[1]}href=\"" . preg_replace('/[^[:print:]]/', '', $matches[2])."\"{$matches[3]}>";  
    },
    $buffer
);
```

Comment: Красавчик , спасибо огромное