# Как правильно настроить чпу?

Tags: .htaccess

Не получается настроить чпу в htaccess

Сейчас: [site.ru/index.php?page=catalog&cat=2499](http://site.ru/index.php?page=catalog&cat=2499)
Нужно: [site.ru/catalog/2499](http://site.ru/catalog/2499)

Вставил строку:

```
RewriteRule ^catalog/(.*)$ index.php?page=catalog&cat=$1 [QSA]
```

в итоге путь сокращается, но работает некорректно.
Написал ещё пару строк:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} " /index\.php\?page=catalog&cat=(.*) "
```

`RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/catalog/%1? [R=301,L]`

Но чувствую я, что они неправильные.
Подскажите как сделать правильное чпу?

Comment: Правильней примерно так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/542869/186083

Comment: получилось, но!
у меня есть уже RewriteRule, и когда добавляю ещё один, они оба перестают работать, а по отдельности работают( 
Почему так?

Comment: Потому что правила могут влиять друг на друга, пересекаться. Если сработало одно из условий и цель запроса изменилась, то проверка условий запускается снова, в результате может получиться зацикливание переадресации.

Comment: да, они похожи? можно их как-то объединить в одну строку? Чтобы работало нормально.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=catalog&cat=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
как их объединить в одну строку?

Comment: Эти два правила работать одновременно не могут. У них условия срабатывания совпадают на 100%.

Comment: А я сделал уже)) и работает все норм)