# Необязательные параметры RewriteRule ЧПУ в .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, чпу

Можно ли указывать необязательные параметры RewriteRule при написании ЧПУ. Допустим есть скрипт с запросом - `cats.php?type=test&id=1&sort=datea&page=1` и для него пишем:

```
RewriteRule ^cats/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ cats.php?type=$1&id=$2&sort=$3&page=$4 [L]
```

А что если допустим, переменная page не обязательна и можно обратиться к скрипту без нее - cats.php?type=test&id=1&sort=datea. Как правильно написать такое правило?

Может быть так?

```
RewriteRule ^cats/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ cats.php?type=$1&id=$2&sort=$3&page=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^cats/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ cats.php?type=$1&id=$2&sort=$3 [L]
```

Забавно, но вот так вот работает:

```
RewriteRule ^cats/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ cats.php?type=$1&id=$2&sort=$3&page=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^cats/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ cats.php?type=$1&id=$2&sort=$3 [L]
```

А вот так вот, нет:

```
RewriteRule ^cats/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ cats.php?type=$1&id=$2&sort=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^cats/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ cats.php?type=$1&id=$2&sort=$3&page=$4 [L]
```

Comment: Делайте единую точку входа, а роутер пишите в php, чтобы не захламлять правилами .htaccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mod_rewrite останавливается на первом правиле, которое подходит.

Строка `cats/1/2/3/4` соответствует и `^cats/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$`, и `^cats/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$`. Если хотите получить свободу перестановки, то побеспокойтесь о том, чтобы соответствующие строки не пересекались. Например, можно заменить `(.*)` на `([^/]*)`. Ну и `*` я бы заменил на `+`, потому что пустых "директорий" уж точно следует избегать.

Для опциональных параметров можете воспользоваться квантификатором `?`, например, `^cats(/([^/]+)(/([^/]+)(/([^/]+)(/([^/]+))?)?)?)?$`. Но это ужас, конечно, и так делать не стоит.

P. S. Такие урлы ни в каком приближении не являются "человекопонятными". Такими правилами вы только запутаете поисковики, которые заблудятся в ваших бесконечных "директориях". Не надо бездумно превращать каждый GET-аргумент в директорию.

P. P. S. Воспользуйтесь роутером на PHP, а не генерируйте кашу в .htaccess. См. "[Как сделать всё и сразу в mod_rewrite?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/542869)"