# Редирект ссылки с GET параметром на ссылк с двумя GET параметрами

Tags: редирект

Здравствуйте! подскажите пожалуйста каким образом сделать редирект c ссылки:

```
http://site.ru/product.php?article=13223112
```

на:

```
http://site.ru/product.php?article=13223112&name=tovarname
```

Добавил при переходе по ссылке еще один параметр, чтобы ключевое слово добавилось в адрес, но получается сейчас у меня дубли

Подойдет ли такое  шаблонное правильно или надо колдовать?

```
RewriteRule ^news/happy.* /news.html [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^article=(\w+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^product\.php$ http://site.ru/product.php?article=%1&name=tovarname [R=301,L]
```

Правда если **tovarname** это строка уникальная для каждой странице, то всю переадресацию придется делать не в .htaccess, а в движке, на котором крутится сайт.

Comment: да, товар нейм уникальная переадресаация с ЧПУ работает только для ссылки с двумя гет параметрами

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^article=([^&]*)&name=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^product\.php$ /%1/%2.html? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /product.php?article=$1&name=$2 [L]


но остается зараза в индексте ссылка с одним гет параметром

Comment: @BulZapatronen, если у вас там куча правил в .htaccess, то бросьте это все. Пишите роутер со всеми правилами на том языке программирования, на котором работает ваш сайт. А в .htaccess делайте просто единую точку входа на подобии этого варианта: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/551401/186083