# Можно ли в htpaccess сделать редирект с ссылки с одним гет на ссылку с двумя гет?

Tags: http-status-code-301

Можно ли в htpaccess сделать редирект с ссылки с одним гет на ссылку с двумя гет?

С ссылки:
http://site.ru/product.php?article=4akb
на
http://site.ru/product.php?article=4akb&name=Boks

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что повтор https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706064/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81-get-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba-%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d1%8f-get-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8