# Удаление лишних слешей

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Есть сайт, где в адресной строке можно ввести вместо одного `/` два и более, а страницы все равно будут открываться(пример: `test//home///page`). Необходимо сделать так чтобы если в адресной строке встречается два и более `/` подряд, ссылаться на ту же самую страницу только уже с нормальными слешами (например: `test/home/page`). Пробовал сделать так:

```
 $pos = strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '//');
                if($pos != '')
                {
                    $link = str_replace ( '//', '/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
                    header('Location: ' . $link .'');
                }
```

Почему-то не берет во внимание слешы в самом начале адреса (например:`test//home/page`).

Comment: RTFM php.net/strpos

Comment: @Ипатьев, почему-то `strpos` не видит первое вхождение

Comment: **RTFM php.net/strpos**

Comment: @r.mcreal, ошибку выдавайте 404 на такие адреса, а не переадресацию.

Comment: @Visman, нужна именно переадресация

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам решение через .htaccess для apache:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} //
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://your.site/$1 [R,L,QSA]
```

На основании [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/551401/186083) ответа.

Comment: это просто в `.htaccess` нужно добавить? А то я с ним до этого не работал

Comment: @r.mcreal, если у вас сервер apache, то да, в .htaccess, который в корне сайта. Если там уже есть `RewriteEngine On`, то сразу после него прописываете 2 и 3 строки из этого ответа.

Answer (score 0):

используйте замену регуляркой

```
$link = preg_replace('/\/+/', '/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Но такое выглядит кривовато (зубочистка), поэтмоу, обычно пишут так:

```
$link = preg_replace('!/+!', '/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Но лучше подобные задачи решать средствами apache/nginx.

Comment: Пишет: `Сайт test выполнил переадресацию слишком много раз.`

Comment: а ка он мог так сделать. Он же должен только один раз это делать

Comment: переадресация много раз происходит, потому что условие в if немного странное. Если strpos ничего не находит, он возвращает false.

Comment: Спасибо большое! До этого делал так: ` if($pos != false){...}`, но забыл что в этом случае `false` будет равно `0` т.е. самому первому элементу, сейчас сравниваю так ` if($pos !== false){...}` и все работает

Comment: @r.mcreal не "забыл", а тебя носом натыкали

Comment: вопрос был не в том как заменять ,А в том как проверять.

Comment: Только вопрос называется "как удалить лишние слеши", а не "как проверить, что есть лишние слеши".

Comment: Согласен, был не прав( Поторопился