# Clean URL на PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

Разрабатывая свою небольшую CMS столкнулся с такой проблемой, необходимо реализовать "чистые ссылки".

У меня есть функция, которая преобразовывает строку в чистую ссылку, в базе у меня есть страницы с его содержимым, не могу понять, как можно настроить вывод контента в зависимости от URL страницы. Знаю, что нужно что-то прописать в htacces, подскажите?

PHP: 5.6
Вот моя функция:

```
function url_cli($str, $replace=array(), $delimiter='-') {
    if( !empty($replace) ) {
        $str = str_replace((array)$replace, ' ', $str);
    }

    $clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
    $clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $clean);
    $clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-'));
    $clean = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $clean);

    return $clean;
}
```

Comment: Делаете перенаправление всех запросов (к несуществующим папкам/файлам) на один файл (например так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/542869/186083 ) и уже в этом файле разбираете пришедший запрос. P.S. И зачем адреса страниц переводить в транслит?

Comment: URL страницы будет формироваться в зависимости от его названия

Comment: Поисковики и браузеры вполне нормально обрабатывают не только латиницу. 21 век все-таки на дворе ;)

Comment: Мне так приятнее, иначе глаз режет)