# Использование единственного Redirect'а к динамическим страницам

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo, redirect

Здравствуйте. У меня генерируются страницы через `ajax-запросы + history.pushState`. При обновлении страницы происходит обработка `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` и формируется правильная страница.
Вопрос: корректно ли будет прописать в `.htaccess` только строчку: `ErrorDocument 404 /index.php`? Или возникнут проблемы с индексацией у поисковых систем?

Обработка урла происходит на php в файле  `index.php`.

Comment: Используйте стандартный подход https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/542869/186083 Но вместо `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_route=$1 [L,QSA]` используйте `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,QSA]` раз данные вы берете из `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Comment: Спасибо, только что нашел подобное )).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел, если кому еще понадобится -- привожу код:

```
RewriteEngine on

 # Don't rewrite files or directories
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
            RewriteRule ^ - [L]

            # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
            RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```