# Как сделать ЧПУ через .htaccess или другим способом

Tags: .htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

Здравствуйте, подскажите как сделать `ЧПУ` через `.htaccess` или другим способом. На данный момент пытаюсь реализовать через `.htaccess`, но что-то не так.

Ситуация такая что использую одну точку входа через `index.php`, может это как-то влияет.

Вот `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/$ ?country=$1&region=$2&city=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если у вас уже единая точка входа (это хорошо) и нет зависимости от .htaccess (это хорошо), то не надо добавлять зависимость от .htaccess и терять достоинства единой точки входа: весь роутинг в одном месте, независимость от сервера.

Разбирайте ваш URL прямо в index.php.

Подробнее: [Как сделать всё и сразу в mod_rewrite?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542869/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%91-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b2-mod-rewrite)

P. S. Не могу закрыть как дубликат вопрос под конкурсом.

P. P. S. Уже ничего не помню про .htaccess, но в вашем коде, вроде, проблема в том, что все преобразования повешены на одно условие.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, это то что нужно!

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess проходится повторно, если были изменения строки запроса условиями.

Осторожнее с `.*` иначе все запросы будут попадать именно туда. Можно использовать `[END]` для остановки повторного прохода. `[L]` останавливает парсинг, но не отменяет повторный проход