# Помочь с ЧПУ (.htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess

Сейчас выводится поиск по меню вот так:
http://domen.ru/view_cat?cat=thrasher&type=tshirts

Нужно чтобы выводилось например вот так:
http://domen.ru/category/thrasher/tshirts

Или же ещё лучше:
http://domen.ru/category/brand-thrasher/type-tshirts

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^sweatshirts/([0-9]+)-([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ view_content.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tshirts/([0-9]+)-([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ view_content.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^jackets/([0-9]+)-([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ view_content.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^shoes/([0-9]+)-([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ view_content.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^socks/([0-9]+)-([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ view_content.php?id=$1 [L]



RewriteRule ^cart/([0-9]+)-([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ cart.php?id=$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{REMOTE_ADDR} !188.190.82.236
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ close.php [L,QSA]
```

Сколько не читал, не смотрел видео - не получается, помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать всё и сразу в mod\_rewrite?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542869/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%91-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b2-mod-rewrite)

Comment: @Visman не дубликат