# ЧПУ (.htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, чпу

Сейчас выводится поиск по меню вот так: http://domen.ru/view_cat?cat=thrasher&type=tshirts

Нужно чтобы выводилось например вот так: http://domen.ru/category/thrasher/tshirts

Или же ещё лучше: http://domen.ru/category/brand-thrasher/type-tshirts

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^sweatshirts/([0-9]+)-([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ view_content.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tshirts/([0-9]+)-([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ view_content.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^jackets/([0-9]+)-([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ view_content.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^shoes/([0-9]+)-([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ view_content.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^socks/([0-9]+)-([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ view_content.php?id=$1 [L]



RewriteRule ^cart/([0-9]+)-([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ cart.php?id=$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{REMOTE_ADDR} !188.190.82.236
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ close.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/802330/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%87%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%a7%d0%9f%d0%a3-htaccess

Comment: @Visman вы что меня не понимаете? там нету того что мне нужно

Comment: Конечно нет. Но тут свои правила, а не ваши. Задали вопрос - ждите ответа, а не плодите новые точно такие же вопросы.

Comment: Пока присутствует ![вот это правило](https://monosnap.com/file/a6L5Uf9M1q3IDLMKS6DkFxydbm3YGv.png) - Работать не будет

Comment: @АндрейProjectSoft необходимо удалить 3 эти строки?

Comment: Я не знаю вашего проекта. На вскидку. По запросу вы подключаете разные въюверы. Вполне возможно, что сеошники вам дали задание - сделать ЧПУ. Но удалив эти три строки вы рискуете, что что-то отвалится. 
Если удалите эти три строки, то вам ещё нужно будет написать правило обработки ссылок типа http://domen.ru/category/brand-thrasher/type-tshirts по аналогии с существующими правилами.

Comment: @АндрейProjectSoft Спасибо что пытаетесь мне помочь, нет не сеошники, меня просто раздражают стандартные ссылки и я хочу сделать красивые, просто там была стандартная строка RewriteRule ^sweatshirts/([0-9]+)-([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ view_content.php?id=$1 [L] и она работает, как сделать по этому же принципу? Пожалуйста, оставьте свои данные или напишите мне idshelestid@gmail.com

Comment: Отправил вам контакт

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы составить правила, нужно понимать регулярки.
https://regex101.com/r/iKv1eo/1

```
RewriteRule ^view_cat(?:\.php)?\?cat=(.+)&(type)=(.+)$ category/$1/$2-$3 [R=301,L]
```

Но нужно понимать, что ваше правило

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Отработает первым.

И вообще.
У вас совершенно неправильное понимание роутинга.
Роутинг должен идти через один единственный файл `index.php`. И уже в нём вы строите всю логику вывода. Подключаете те файлы, которые вам нужно, следуя параметрам, которые переданы в `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`
Тем самым вы избавитесь от километров правил в `.htaccess` и вам на много легче будет отловить ошибки.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/542869/186083

Comment: Ну да, я именно об этом.

Comment: @АндрейProjectSoft не работает...

Comment: @КсенияФитенко я же предупреждал о первом правиле, где вы подключаете файлы согласно запросам. Оно отработает первым и не будут выполняться следующие правила.  Покажите полный код htaccess

Comment: @АндрейProjectSoft весь htaccess приложен, больше там ничего не указано, там есть один пример RewriteRule ^sweatshirts/([0-9]+)-([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ view_content.php?id=$1 [L] он работает, но вот то что подсказали мне Вы, к сожалению, не работает

Answer (score 0):

htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /view_cat(?:\.php)?\?cat=(.*)&type=([a-z0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /category/%1/type-%2/? [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

index.php

```
<?php
header("Content-type:text/plain;charset=utf-8");
print_r($_GET['q']);
echo PHP_EOL;
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

Рабочий, протестирован.

Comment: Можно, пожалуйста, Ваши контакты? Всё равно не работает... $$$ - приветствуется