# Как заменить url типа — «/page.php?id=4» на «/contact» и т.п.?

Tags: php

Подскажите, как заменить url типа — «**/page.php?id=4**» на «**/contact**» *(или другое, взависимости от столбца title в БД)*. Если можно, простой пример

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать всё и сразу в mod\_rewrite?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542869/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%91-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b2-mod-rewrite)

Comment: настройте `htaccess` так чтобы `contact` передавалось в скприт как параметр. В скрипте найдите соответствие в БД и определите ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

index.php

```
/* Получаем URL в переменную $result в случае yourdomain.com/name-page.html в $result окажется строка: /name-page.html */
$result = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

/* проверяем, что бы в URL не было ничего, кроме символов алфавита (a-zA-Z), цифр (0-9), а также . / - _ # в противном случае - выдать ошибку 404 */
if (preg_match ('/([^a-zA-Z0-9\.\/\-\_\#])/', $result)) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    echo 'Недопустимые символы в URL';
    exit;
}

/* отбрасываем из ЧПУ всё лишнее, оставляя только имя виртуального html-файла. В случае с  yourdomain.com/name-page.html это будет name-page функция preg_split формирует массив, разбивая переданную строку по заданной маске. */
$array_url = preg_split ('/(\/|\..*$)/', $result,-1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

/* в случае, если обращение было только к домену (yourdomain.com/ или yourdomain.com), в $array_url будет пустой результат, такое событие нужно обработать, как страницу с ID_page = 1 */
if (!$array_url) {
    $ID_page = 1;
}else{
    $sef_value = $array_url[0];
/* Далее идёт запрос в БД о наличие в столбце SEF строки $sef_value при положительном ответе получаем из БД соответствующий $sef_value $ID_page, если такой строки не найдено - выводим страницу ошибки 404. */
}
/* Теперь обычная обработка, как если бы $ID_page был получен методом GET */
```

Это не лучший пример, но он должен помочь. Детальнее про [организацию ЧПУ](https://keengo.ru/blog/php/kak-sdelat-chpu-dlya-sayta/)

Comment: а сразу эти проверки регулярок на 404 нельзя было сделать в хтаксесс?