# Передача странице PHP GET переменных

Tags: php, get

У меня есть страница, которая принимает GET переменные

```
blabla.ru/index?e=123
```

Но такой вид ссылки выглядит не очень.
Видел, что на многих сайтах, например новости, отображаются по пути типа

```
blabla.ru/news/123/
```

Не думаю, что под каждую новость у них создаётся страница. Как можно передавать переменную по ссылке в таком виде?
Я что-то слышал про *query field* или *path field*, вроде так называется, но гугля эти названия ничего не нашёл =(
Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать всё и сразу в mod\_rewrite?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542869/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%91-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b2-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо ознакомиться с понятием роутингов на PHP. 
В случае когда вы используйте хостинг у вас имеется замечательный файл `.htaccess`, если его нет, то создайте его в корне сайта.

Этот файл поможет вам направить пользователя на специальный файл который будет отображать содержимое. Вот например такой код, который укажет что если человек обратился не к файлу и не к папке, то открыть запустить файл `router.php`

Код для `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^.*$ router.php [QSA,L]
```

В свою очередь в файле `router.php` который лежит рядом с `.htaccess` вы получаете адрес который вбил пользователь и разбираете его по кусочкам

```
$path = explode('/', filter_var($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
```

В итоге здесь у меня массив `$path` в котором есть части пути разделяемые слешем.
Далее если примитивно, то пишем

```
if($path[2]=='superPage'){
  require_once('pages/superpage.php');
}
```

Если пользователь зашел на страницу `mydomen/dir/superPage`
то вы ему откроете `pages/superpage.php` хотя url выглядит красивее)
Ну а вместо гет запроса тогда можно просто использовать часть пути, хотя идея так себе. В современности, приложения посылают данные с помощью JS.

Как то так)

Comment: А переменные без конвертирования ссылки в ? и = можно как-то? А то такой способ интересный, но ведь он всё равно приведёт ссылку к такому виду

Comment: @Дмитрий У вас нет необходимости использовать $_GET теперь, вместо этого вы параметры кладёте прямо в URL
Например
mydomen/shop/item.php?tovar=red_marker
теперь можно написать так
mydomen/shop/tovar/red_marker
и получить его не в $_GET, а в массиве $path о котором я писал в ответе.