# Как создать редирект через htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

Надо сделать редирект так чтобы со страницы `https://example.com/id1` на страницу `https://example.com/id.php?id=1` при это цифра после `id` может быть любая, к примеру `131` или `92`.

Comment: PS: файл .htaccess кристально чист!

Comment: зачем прошлую тему удалили? я же вам там ответил.... эх...

Comment: я до конца не понял как это сделать, вписал ваш код но чуда не произошло.

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5b.htaccess%5d%20%d1%87%d0%bf%d1%83&searchOn=3)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать всё и сразу в mod\_rewrite?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542869/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%91-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b2-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.htaccess`:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from All

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^www\.].*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9_\-/]+)/?$ /index.php?sef=$1 [L]
```

А на странице `index.php` уже работать с `$_GET['sef']`.