# Можно ли в .htaccess поставить такое условие

Tags: php, .htaccess

Можно ли в .htaccess поставить такое условие, если по корню /sveden/ ошибка 404 то перенаправлять на корень /svedeniya/, например https://academy-andriaka-dev.v1.cloud.clickon.pro/sveden/employees/ выдает 404, и перенаправить ее на https://academy-andriaka-dev.v1.cloud.clickon.pro/svedeniya/employees/ 301 редиректом.

Так вот подскажите правило для этого, спасибо огромное!!!!

Comment: вряд ли вас интересует буквальный ответ на ваш вопрос. переформулируйте, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) так, чтобы на него можно было дать полноценный ответ

Comment: @aleksandr-barakin, изменил, мне нужно правило как это конкретно сделать)

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.htaccess). возможно и [первый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542869/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%91-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b2-mod-rewrite) уже отвечает на вопрос.